# Find documents with array of objectIds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an array of objectIds represented as strings.

```
["594c7a30f8f774268a2cdd14","594c7a30f8f774268a2cdd13"]
```

In my aggregation, I dynamically build a match object with this array along with other fields.

```
match["_id"] = { $in: classes};
```

This doesn't work and I assume becuase it's just an array of strings instead of objectIDs like ObjectId("594c7a30f8f774268a2cdd14").

How do I build the match so that _id search works with the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by changing the match from

```
match["_id"] = { $in: classes};
```

to

```
match._id = { $in: classes.map(mongoose.Types.ObjectId)};
```

The map function is what I needed.